# Setup Audit Trail entries from salesforce.com

Tags: setup

Would anyone happen to know what the following three entries from salesforce.com mean? They seem to be appearing together at the same time every few days. And there is never any change happening, the Active Scratch Org Limit is still 80 and the Daily Scratch Org limit is still 160. When looking at the status of the instance, there is no maintenance that corresponds to the timestamps. It seems there is something changing in the system and this is a consequence of that.

| User | Action |
| --- | --- |
| salesforce.com, inc. | Changed Provisioned Active Scratch Org Limit from 80 to 80 |
| salesforce.com, inc. | Max number of streaming topics |
| salesforce.com, inc. | Changed Provisioned Daily Scratch Org Limit from 160 to 160 |

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal and expected part of how Salesforce maintains an organization. The user exists at the time that an organization is created and may be used by Salesforce to make automated system-level changes in the course of patch releases and updates on your org/instance. These are due to DB scripts that are automated in the background for limits provisioning and it technically appears that some org features have been checked.

These changes do not impact your org and nothing to worry about it.  Check more details on [Changes from Automated Process User in Setup Audit Trail](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387937&type=1).